# Help understanding lilliefors test

Tags: normal-distribution, signal-processing, lilliefors-test

I need some help understanding the meaning of the lilliefors test. As far as I know, the lilliefors method provides a measure of normality of a data set. That is, a measure of how the images (values) of the signal distribute in a normal distribution. That being said, I am implementing a method on python for performing a lilliefors test on a signal, a very long signal, and I am using the statsmodel package implementation of this test. I am having trouble understanding the result of the signal since I get the ksstat and pvalue as output.

When I run the test over my signal, I am getting a 0.10181772836381899 as Kolmogorov-Smirnov test statistic with estimated mean and variance and a 0.0009999999999998899 as p-value. I don't know much about statistics so I don't know how to interpret this result.

Could you explain me what those values mean or provide me any other implementation of this test for python with a better documentation?

Here is the documentation of the lilliefors method from statsmodel package:
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.lilliefors.html

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to CV! Unfortunately, your characterization of this test is incorrect and the value of conducting any formal hypothesis test of normality in a "very long signal" is dubious. Perhaps those are issues better worth addressing then getting your software to work?

Comment: I understand... I know my signal follows some kind of normal distribution since the majority of the values are surrounding a value between the centre of the signal and the maximum of the signal. I would like to have a measurement of the normality of the signal values but... I don't know which method to apply. What would you suggest in your experience? I know it's a broad question..

Comment: It still is not at all evident what use a "measurement of normality" might be. Moreover, many signals will produce very Normal-looking values merely because they swing all over the place and things average out.